# What exactly is deregister_tm_clones and register_tm_clones?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, elf, disassembly

What exactly are deregister_tm_clones and register_tm_clones and why are inserted in .text section? How can i find what code is inserted in my ELF besides the code I write?

Comment: *How can i find what code is inserted in my ELF besides the code I write?* That part's easy: add `-v` to your `gcc` command line so it prints the exact linker command it uses.  That will include the CRT startup files like `/usr/lib/Scrt1.o` or `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/crtbegin.o`.  Did you really want a specific detailed description of just `register_tm_clones`, or just a general idea of what `_start` and other CRT code does in general?  (call libc init functions, set up args for main.)

Comment: Well, I want to find what library code is inserted in my ELF and those 2 are in .text section where is all the other code i wrote. And would like both a detailed description and a general idea if you have the time to provide them.

Comment: What platform are you on?  GNU/Linux I assume, unless something else uses ELF?  Android/ELF?  On x86-64 GNU/Linux ELF, I see `__libc_csu_init` and a couple other labels from CRT code.  Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0 and http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

Comment: I am on Linux. What else is statically linked?

Comment: I already told you exactly how to find that out, in my first comment.  Look at `gcc -v foo.c` output to see the linker command line.  The linker doesn't magically link anything not mentioned on its command line, so that's the full list.